# How do I debug intermittent System Crashes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debugging

Linux/Xorg crashes intermittently on Debian Stretch with a swap partition - **display goes all black** or leaves the background image. I **have to hard reset** the box.

1. No logs (*Xorg.0.log* or *syslog*) are being generated at the point of crash and **SysRq doesn't work**.
2. No stacktraces/coredumps either.
3. Currently I'm running hddtemp every 60s to see if there's a problem with disk - no SMART errors.

What's the best way to troubleshoot something like this? Can I poll something or do something else to gather more data.